# IE7 problem with Sliding Tabs

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, tabs, slider

I'm having a problem with my sliding tabs in IE7. I'm using these sliding tabs (http://www.queness.com/post/274/jquery-sliding-tab-menu-for-sidebar-tutorial)

You can see the problem on my site (http://wpmaniac.com/leetpress/) in the sidebar under "Latest Reviews".

The sliding tabs are working fine in all other browsers. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is in IE7.

Here's a screenshot of what's wrong in IE7:
[image: IE7 fails]

Thanks

Comment: I think IE7's the problem, not your site. Welcome to the second stage of web design: making it work in IE...

Comment: IE sure is a pain in the ass ;) I hope someone can spot the problem though! :)

Comment: Since I (and many people) don't use IE7, could you screenshot and/or describe the problem? It's easier to fix if I know what's wrong (I run Linux, so no IE for me).

Comment: Yeah of course, http://wpmaniac.com/leetpress/ie7-problem.jpg

Comment: I've added it to your question, as you can't add images.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an overflow problem to me. Here's what I would try:

```
#panel
{
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: It did not work, though. But i found out that the problem is that my <div class="side-item"> has "position:relative" on. I wonder why IE7 don't like that :S